# Python reading JSON file obtained via API

Tags: python-3.x, api

I am a newbie in Python and API but I am just wondering what I am doing wrong since the data that I got via API and copied/saved into the file (.json), now I am not able to open it in python.
So, the data from API looks like in the picture below:
[image]

[image]

Now, I have started with python code:

```
import json

with open('json_api_test.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    print(d)
```

And the error that I am getting is:

File "C:\Users\XX9999\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 64 column 1 (char 1183)

Comment: ...and when you look at line 64, column 1 of `json_api_test.json`, what do you see?

Comment: Yes, when I uploaded the file on json online reader I found an issue within the file. So, I corrected the file and applied:  
       `with open('json_api_test.json') as f: 
        d = json.load(f)
        df = pd.json_normalize(d['data'])
        table1.append(df)`
It works now.